# SPFolder.Item does not return SPListItem associated with SPFolder in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have following powershell:

```
    $webUrl = 'http://demo2010a:90/sites/Contracts'
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl;
    $lists = $web.GetListsOfType($SPBaseTypeDocumentLibrary);
    foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
    $folders = $list.Folders
    foreach ($spFolder in $folders)
    {   

        #$item = $spFolder.Item
        $item = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]::$spFolder.Item
        if ($item -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Host "Null found"
        }
        else
        {
        }   
     }
     }

     $web.Dispose()
```

The problem is I can't seem to get SPListItem from SPFolder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting it. $list.Folders is a collection of SPListItems so $spFolder is already a SPListItem. Just $item = $spFolder is enough.

SPListItem.Item is used to get or set the value that is contained by the specified field.