# Every SPFile is null in a document library using PowerShell?

Tags: document-library, powershell, spfile

What the crap is this about?

I whipped up a fairly simple run-once and discard PowerShell script to iterate through all of the files in a list and make a simple change. The problem is every SPFile I get back is null. Every last one of them.

Now I understand that sometimes this is the case (like with forms: [SPFile.Item == null and SPFolder.Item == null](https://www.thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2007/09/24/spfile-item-==-null-and-spfolder-item-==-null.aspx)), but not on every last frigging file. I ran null checks up the hierarchy of my objects, and $folder is not null, but $file is. Seriously, what is wrong with this?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders)
{
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files)
    {
        // $file is null here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, `SPList.Folders` actually returns an `SPListItemCollection`, not an `SPFolderCollection`...

However, `SPList.RootFolder.SubFolders` does return an `SPFolderCollection`...

Comment: I was under the same impression once that SPList.Folders returns SPFOlderCollection. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49810/spfolder-item-does-not-return-splistitem-associated-with-spfolder-in-powershell